# How to close the safari pop up dialogue when running automate script with nightwatch on BrowserStack?

Tags: browserstack, nightwatch

I use Browserstack to do the E2E testing, now I met a problem when I try to run the mobile automate script in safari on Browserstack, there will have a pop-up dialogue show when I click a button which will result in opening a new tab, the dialogue show message like this: 'this site is attempting to open a popup window', I must close it and the script can continue executing.

Now the problem is:
1. When I click the button which will trigger this pop-up dialogue, there will always show an exception in the log: 'Error while running .clickElement() protocol action: Appium error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Did not get any response after 20s'.
2. I can use the XPath to locate the button on the pop-up dialogue and click it to close the dialogue, but it takes serval minutes, is there another way to do this operation more efficient?

```
const { client } = require('nightwatch-api')
const { Given, Then, When} = require('cucumber')

Given('open mobile 163 news', async function () {
    await client.url('https://3g.163.com/news/article/EJN99AOF000189FH.html?clickfrom=index2018_news_newslist#offset=0')
})

When('choose share by QQ', async function () {
    await client.waitForElementVisible('.sharelogo')
    await client.click('.sharelogo')
})

Then('the popup should show', async function () {
    await client.waitForElementVisible('.qzone')
    await client.click('.qzone')
    await client.setContext('NATIVE_APP')
    await client.source(function(res){
        console.log(res.value)
    })
    await client.useXpath()
    await client.click('//*[@name="Allow"]')
    await client.contexts(function(result) {
        client.setContext(result.value[result.value.length - 1])
        client.useCss()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the capability 'nativeWebTap' and setting it to the value 'true' in the test scripts?

Comment: Can I add this 'nativeWebTap' into desiredCapabilities of nightwatch.conf.js?I try it, but still need several minutes to perform the click operation,my nightwatch.conf.js is like this:
chrome_bs : {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        'browserstack.user': 'xxx',
        'browserstack.key': 'xxx',
        'os': 'Windows',
        'os_version': '10',
        'browser': 'Chrome',
        'browser_version': '70.0',
        'resolution': '1920x1080',
        'browserstack.debug': 'true',
        'browserstack.networkLogs': 'true',
        'nativeWebTap': 'true'
   }
}